# Java: read groups of lines with same prefix from very large text file

Tags: java, file, text, line, bufferedreader

I have a large (~100GB) text file structured like this:

```
A,foobar
A,barfoo
A,foobar
B,barfoo
B,barfoo
C,foobar
```

Each line is a comma-separated pair of values. The file is sorted by the first value in the pair. The lines are variable length. Define a group as being all lines with a common first value, i.e. with the example quoted above all lines starting with "A," would be a group, all lines starting with "B," would be another group.

The entire file is too large to fit into memory, but if you took all the lines from any individual group will always fit into memory.

I have a routine for processing a single such group of lines and writing to a text file. My problem is that I don't know how best to read the file a group at a time. All the groups are of arbitrary, unknown size. I have considered two ways:

1) Scan the file using a `BufferedReader`, accumulating the lines from a group in a String or array. Whenever a line is encountered that belongs to a new group, hold that line in a temporary variable, process the previous group. Clear the accumulator, add the temporary and then continue reading the new group starting from the second line.

2) Scan the file using a `BufferedReader`, whenever a line is encountered that belongs to a new group, somehow reset the cursor so that when `readLine()` is next invoked it starts from the first line of the group instead of the second. I have looked into `mark()` and `reset()` but these require knowing the byte-position of the start of the line.

I'm going to go with (1) at the moment, but I would be very grateful if someone could suggest a method that smells less.

Comment: Do you want to search the specific group or do you want to do real whole values

Comment: @RJ45 for all the lines in each group I need to perform a computation on every line in the group, perform a computation aggregating the results from the individual lines, and write a result to disk.

Comment: This seems like a potential candidate for https://github.com/fge/largetext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a [PushbackReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html) would work:

```
 if (lineBelongsToNewGroup){
     reader.unread(lastLine.toCharArray());
     // probably also unread a newline
 }
```

Comment: too bad that it doesn't understand lines. Not sure how to combine it with a BufferedReader.

Comment: Thanks Thilo. You've understood correctly what I wanted. I needed a clean way to read groups of lines, essentially something like:

`while (thereAreGroupsRemaining)
{
    String s = readNextGroup();
    process(s);
}
`

Answer (score 1):

I think option 1 is the simplest.  I would parse the text yourself, rather than use BufferedReader as it will take a lone time to parse 100 GB.

The only option which is likely to be faster is to use a binary search accessing the file using RandomAccessFile. You can memory map 100 GB on a 64-bit JVM.  This avoids the need to parse every line which is pretty expensive. An advantage of this approach is that you can use multiple threads  Its is far, far more complicated to implement, but should be much faster.  Once you have each boundary, you can copy the raw data in bulk without having to parse all the lines.

Comment: I think he wants to read the whole file (not just a single group).

Comment: @Thilo True, but the OP only needs to find the first and last line of each group. Using random access you can avoid reading as Strings all the lines in between. Once you have the position of the first line and the position of the first line of the next group, you can copy from ByteBuffer to FileChannel efficiently. And its a search you can perform multi-threaded.

Comment: But he'll want to have all the lines (as Strings) in between, too. This strikes me as a one-pass streaming operation, eventually reading every line exactly once (plus a bit of rewinding at the start of every group), no need for random access. But maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Thilo You can read every line individually, it just that this is very slow. esp when you don't need to parse every line.

Comment: I don't know... It seems that he needs to read a whole group into memory anyway for the next operation. So even if skipping around with a binary search made detecting the boundaries faster, the next step would be reading the whole group again (which presumably also involves the parsing, at the very least to look for line endings to split the data in lines, which seems to be not much different than looking for a comma).

Comment: Did a quick test where reading 1 GB took 27 seconds. So I would guess that reading lines with BufferedReader.readLine() of 100 GB would take 45 minutes. Once you know the location of the start and the end of the group you can copy from a direct ByteBuffer to a FileChannel without the data being parsed or brought into Java space at all. You don't need to parse the individual lines or create objects from their ends.

Comment: if the next operation can be done without bringing the data into Java space. How long does it take to establish all boundaries on that 1GB file? Anyway, +1 for effort now ;-)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help.

Just to clarify: 
1) I need to read every line in every group.
2) This is a one-off operation, I'm sure that disk I/O will be the greatest bottleneck, and it is acceptable for it to run for a few hours.

Comment: If speed is not too important I would do it the simplest way which works.  I still get the impression you only need to *copy* ever line, not readLine() every line. With readLine() you can read between 30+ MB per second depending on your processor which is close to the maximum speed of a HDD.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks. How would your faster copy method be implemented? How would it be more/less flexible than `readLine()`?

Comment: @advait readLine() has to read and copy each character, decoded from bytes sequentially to find the end of each line. Finally produce a `String` object. This takes a fair bit of work. Reading the bytes randomly you can find the newline and the group name without decoding the bytes and you can use a binary search to find the start and end without parsing all the lines in between. Once you have the start and end you can perform a bulk copy using direct memory without having read into Java most of the bytes in the middle of the group. This would be faster for the program, *not* the developer ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Comprehensive and easy to understand, thanks! I think as far as my software development skills are concerned: (time to develop faster version + time to run faster version) > (time to develop slower version + time to run slower version) so I will have to go with the simpler method for now :)

Comment: @advait Agreed. Its only if you have really large files you would even consider it worth the effort. ;)